# file_exists(): Unable to find the wrapper "private" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?

Tags: files, stream-wrappers

I just installed a bare boned Drupal 10 locally. and Windows 10 with PHP 8.1.14

I set the private file path as follows:

```
$settings['file_private_path'] = $app_root . '/../private';
```

Its path shows correct "**/admin/config/media/file-system**". Now when I went to Drupal status page, it shows

`Warning: file_exists(): Unable to find the wrapper "private" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? in Drupal\Component\FileSecurity\FileSecurity::writeFile() (line 152 of core\lib\Drupal\Component\FileSecurity\FileSecurity.php).`

I applied the security code for the .htaccess file, but still showing this

[image]

Then I added a code snippet in the theme preprocess function like this:

```
if(file_exists('private://.htaccess')) {
    print 'I found it<br>';
}
else {
    print 'It does not exists<br>';
}
```

It always shows file does not exists. But of course file is there.

I did not face this issue in previous Drupal versions. Btw, in my php.ini allow_url_fopen is On and opessl is enabled.

Anyone there to help me to fix this issue?

Comment: Can you confirm you followed all directions, including clearing the caches? https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/-/blob/11.x/sites/default/default.settings.php?ref_type=heads#L614

Comment: yes, directories are there and cleared cache several times.

Comment: According to what is in the Question this should be working. So the Question needs more information. You’ve missed something on your end.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! To add to what @cilefen said, it is not clear what  *Its path shows correct "/admin/config/media/file-system"* would mean. */admin/config/media/file-system* is the path for the *File system* settings page, which eventually would show the private file system path. The problem is not that path, but the fact that for PHP private:// is not defined as stream wrapper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not say what happened. But reinstalling the Drupal dump fixed the problem.